# Azure AD B2C tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

Last time (8 months ago), I created Azure AD B2C and used Custom policy with Funcs: Sign In (Web) --> It worked well.
But now, when I create again It cannot work. And this is postman message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzeZM.png)

Error message is wrong User & Password.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAN1E.png)

Any one faced the same issue with me?

Comment: Which document do you refer to?

Comment: I followed this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started

Comment: Is your user a local account？if your user is a guest type, this error is raised.

Comment: Hi @ChauncyZhou,
Thanks for your response.  The user is a member of Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the absence of this user name in b2c, which is raised if the user is not created in b2c or registered, as shown in the figure, the user comes from an external ad or guest type.[image]